# django rest framework get data from foreign key relation Post method is not working in Angular2

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, angular2-services

**serializers.py**

After adding this two variables  (**category**,**type_units**) for dropdown post method not working. it through 500 server error And also added my view.py models.py

```
  class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
            category = serializers.CharField(source='category.category', read_only=True)
            type_units = serializers.CharField(source='type_units.type', read_only=True)

            class Meta:
                  model = Product
                  fields = ('id','image','pro_name','description','category','sales','cost','taxable','type_units','hsn')
```

**Models.py**

```
class Units(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/",blank=True,null=True)
    pro_name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    taxable = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    type_units = models.ForeignKey(Units, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hsn = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
class UnitsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Units.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitsSerializer


class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

Comment: can you post your models and your views? And your traceback as well please

Comment: Thank for reply  and i have add above.